# HTML not working with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It seems that the JavaScript won't run when I put it in the html with `<script></script>` but it works fine with the online tool. They JavaScript should be able to replace the image with the video when the image is clicked. How can I add into html?

It work fine while using this online tool 
http://jsfiddle.net/odoycz6n/3/

html

```
<img src="http://www.whatever9495.com/template/damei_d21/image/logo.png" data-video="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwbk-P9knHkGa21vSzYzMFl6YXM/preview">
```

javascript

```
$('img').click(function() {
  video = '<iframe src="' + $(this).attr('data-video') + '"   width="715" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
  $(this).replaceWith(video);
});
```

Comment: Are you including jQuery? How are you adding your scripts to your HTML?

Comment: java has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: My guess if you are not loading your code onload like the fiddle is.

Comment: @MikeC I am not sure how to add scripts to HTML

Comment: See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @EdmundYau Then you [might want to start here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics)

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle loads jQuery by default. You need to load jQuery before using it in your own code like

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, jsFiddle doesn't load jQuery, or any library by default. It does however, default to loading the JavaScript code in the `window.onload` event.

Comment: jsfiddel doesn't load any libraries by default

Answer (score 0):

Just insert `<script>` below `<img >`

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://www.whatever9495.com/template/damei_d21/image/logo.png" data-video="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwbk-P9knHkGa21vSzYzMFl6YXM/preview">
<script>
$('img').click(function() {
video = '<iframe src="' + $(this).attr('data-video') + '"   width="715" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
$(this).replaceWith(video);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```